# rolling geometric means using dplyr and tbrf

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to use dplyr and tbrf to calculate a 90 day rolling geometric mean and 90th percentile for each group 'Type'. The code below is generating percentiles for each date, not every 90 days. It also is wrongly generating duplicate rows.

side note:I first tried using %within% and creating an interval in the lubridate package.However, class Interval from lubridate is currently not supported in dplyr hence wanting to try tbrf. I have also tried tibbletime,RcppRoll and zoo's Rollapply

```
##sample data###

Value=c(50,900,25,25,125,50,25,25,2000,25,25,
25,25,25,25,25,25,325,25,300,475,25)
Dates = as.Date(c("2015-02-23","2015-04-20","2015-06-17",
"2015-08-20","2015-10-05","2015-12-22",
"2016-01-19","2016-03-29","2016-05-03",
"2016-07-21","2016-09-08","2016-11-07",
"2017-02-27","2017-04-19","2017-06-29",
"2017-08-24","2017-10-23","2017-12-28",
"2018-01-16","2018-03-14","2018-05-29",
"2018-07-24"))
Type = c(rep("A", 11), rep("B", 11))

df=data.frame(Value,Dates,Type)



######failed attempt 1####
df2=df %>% group_by(Type) %>% 
 tbr_gmean(Value, Dates, "days", 90) %>%
  tbr_misc(Value, Dates,"days",  90, quantile, .(0.9)) 

 ## failed attempt #2##
 start.date = min(df$Dates)
 breaks = seq(start.date - 30*3600*24, start.date + 30*3600*24, "90 days")
 df$group = cut(df$Dates, breaks=breaks)
 DF= df %>% group_by(Type,group) %>% 
 mutate(Count=n(),gm=geoMean(Value),
 percentile_90=quantile(Value,0.90))
```

Comment: Have you checked the code `as.Date(c(5:20))`

Comment: Yea. It generates 16 sequential dates

Comment: For me, it is giving errors `as.Date(c(5:20))#
Error in as.Date.numeric(c(5:20)) : 'origin' must be supplied`

Comment: Don't you mean `Dates1 <- as.Date(Sys.Date() + 5:20)`?

Comment: weird. I'll change it for you

Comment: I think you need `qnt <- function(x) quantile(x, prob = 0.9)
 df %>% group_by(Type) %>% 
  tbr_gmean(Value, Dates, "days", 5) %>%
   tbr_misc(Value, Dates,"days",  5, qnt, prob = 0.9)`

Comment: For me that still generates the "result" for every day, not for every 5 days

Comment: For me, it is generating 32 rows instead of 160 from your code

Comment: I have 32 rows with a "results" value for each row. It should only produce one value for every 5 day period.

Comment: @shum are your days always sequential for each group? if yes, I will post my solution!

Comment: Unfortunately, the dates are not sequential.@ShirinYavari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: Try this:

```
library(psych)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
dfmod<-df %>% 
    group_by(Type) %>% 
      arrange(Dates) %>%
        mutate(rnk = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Dates) > 5)))%>% #changed it from !=1 to reflect that you want the date difference to be within 5 days or less
          group_by(Type,rnk) %>% 
            mutate(GM = rollapply(Value, 2, geometric.mean, fill=NA, align="right"),
                    qt=rollapply(Value, 2, quantile, p=0.90, fill=NA, align="right")) #changed 5 to 2 so that the rolling sum is calculated for every 2 rows 
 head(dfmod)
## A tibble: 6 x 6
## Groups:   Type, rnk [1]
#  Dates      Type  Value   rnk    GM    qt
#  <date>     <fct> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2018-10-03 A      35.3     1  NA    NA  
#2 2018-10-04 A      34.3     1  NA    NA  
#3 2018-10-05 A      34.6     1  NA    NA  
#4 2018-10-06 A      34.3     1  NA    NA  
#5 2018-10-07 A      34.1     1  34.5  35.1
#6 2018-10-08 A      34.7     1  34.4  34.6
```

Comment: @shum my edits should cover those issues. Hope it works!

Comment: @shum I thought you were going to edit your dataset?!

Comment: Changed the rolling period in the question from 5 days to 90 days and updated the dataset with more realistic dates.... and your code worked! @ShirinYavari